# Executing unit test using jest not covering a callback function inside a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this function

```
1: 
function OnRangeChange(elementID) {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    const queryName = element.getAttribute('data-technicalname');
    element.noUiSlider.on('change', (values, handle) => {
      $(`.range-reset.${queryName}`).removeClass('hidden');
      fetchProductsOnRangeChange(values, element);
    });
  }

// And a unit test  

test('should fetch new products on rangeSlider change using OnRangeChange', () => {
    const elementID = 'twobuttons-range_0';
    window.twoButtonsRangeSliderComponent.OnRangeChange(elementID)
    expect($(`.range-reset.laenge`).hasClass('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
  });

2: 
function fetchProductsOnRangeChange(values, element) {
    // on Range Slider change trigger a new ajax and call renderFilterResults to render new products and all filter settings
    let queryName = element.getAttribute('data-technicalname'),
      unit = element.getAttribute('data-unit'),
      queryValue = `${values[0]}${unit}-${values[1]}${unit}`;
    window.ZEP.ProductFilter.onSelectionClick(queryName, queryValue, 'single');
    window.ZEP.ProductFilter.getFilterDataByParameters(function(error, data) {
      if (!error) {
         $('.product-list-wrapper').text(data)
      } else {
        $('.product-list-wrapper').empty();
         $('.product-list-wrapper').text(`Ajax call failed- ${error.status}:${error.statusText}`);
      }
    });
  }
```

which calls a callback function on the noUiSlider change event. I have written a unit test to test the function OnRangeChange, but the callback function for the on change event is not covered by jest test coverage.
The same happens for the 2 function I have added the getFilterDataByParameters callback is highlighted red as not covered .
How do I get jest to cover the callback function of the on change event?